# Solve $v^3v_x+2(ax+by)v_y=bv$ using method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, solution-verification, characteristics

For real coefficients $a,b$ solve the PDE $$v^3v_x+2(ax+by)v_y=bv, \qquad v(0,y)=f(y).$$

I set a characteristic space $(y_0,s)$

$x(s=0)=0$

$y(s=0)=y_0$

$v(s=0)=f(y_0)$

And write out the characteristic equations:

$dx/ds=v^3\implies x=v^3s$;

$dy/ds=2ax+2by\implies y=y_0e^{2bs}-ax/b$;

$dv/ds=bv\implies v=f(y_0)e^{bs}$;

Now i can find $s$ and $y_0$: $s=x/v^3$, $y_0=(y+ax/b)e^{-2bx/v^3}$.

And i get that $v=f[(y+ax/b)e^{-2bx/v^3}]e^{bx/v^3}$, which is not solvable, because $v$ is a function of an arbitrary function which contains $v$ itself. How do i find the general solution then? Or is this expresseion still considered to be the general solution , even though $v$ is a function of itself?

Comment: How did you go from $dx/ds=v^3$ to $x=v^3s$? $v$ is not a constant with respect to $s$. In fact, you yourself found out how $v$ varies with $s$: $v=f(y_0)e^{bs}$

Comment: @IshanDeo oh, thanks, i wasn't thinking about that at all. how should i solve $dx/ds=v^3$ then?

Comment: @IshanDeo i think i figured it out myself - i should solve the equation for v first!

Comment: If you think you've solved it, I would suggest writing up and posting it as an answer to your own question. That way, we can verify if the solution is right and you can get some rep out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$v^3v_x+2(ax+by)v_y=bv$$
Your equations written on an equivalent form :
$$\frac{dx}{v^3}=\frac{dy}{2(ax+by)}=\frac{dv}{bv}=ds$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{v^3}=\frac{dv}{bv}$ :
$$v^3-3bx=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{v^3}=\frac{dy}{2(ax+by)}$

With $v^3=c_1+3bx\quad;\quad \frac{dx}{c_1+3bx}=\frac{dy}{2(ax+by)}\quad;\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2(ax+by)}{c_1+3bx}$

This is a first order linear ODE. Solving it leads to : $y=\frac{a}{b^2}(c_1+2bx)+c_2(c_1+3bx)^{2/3}$

$\frac{y-\frac{a}{b^2}(c_1+2bx)}{(c_1+3bx)^{2/3}}=c_2\quad$ and with $c_1=v^3-3bx\quad$ we get $\quad \frac{y-\frac{a}{b^2}(v^3-bx)}{(v^3)^{2/3}}=c_2$
$$\frac{1}{v^2}\left(y-\frac{a}{b^2}(v^3-bx) \right)=c_2$$

The general solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $c_2=\Phi(c_1)$ is :
$$\boxed{\frac{1}{v^2}\left(y-\frac{a}{b^2}(v^3-bx) \right)=\Phi\left(v^3-3bx\right)}$$
$\Phi$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to the boundary condition:  $v(0,y)=f(y)$

$\frac{1}{f(y)^2}\left(y-\frac{a}{b^2}(f(y)^3) \right)=\Phi\left(f(y)^3\right)$

Let $f(y)^3=X\quad;\quad f(y)=X^{1/3}\quad;\quad y=f^{-1}\left(X^{1/3}\right)$

$f^{-1}$ means the inverse function.
$$\Phi(X)=\frac{1}{X^{2/3}}\left(f^{-1}\left(X^{1/3}\right)-\frac{a}{b^2}X \right)$$
Now the function $\Phi(x)$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=(v^3-3bx)$ :
$$\frac{1}{v^2}\left(y-\frac{a}{b^2}(v^3-bx) \right)=\frac{1}{(v^3-3bx)^{2/3}}\left(f^{-1}\left((v^3-3bx)^{1/3}\right)-\frac{a}{b^2}(v^3-3bx)\right)$$
This is the solution on the form of implicit equation. Honestly I am not sure that there is no mistake in the calculus because the result appears too complicated for an academic exercise.

Comment: Thank you! Believe it or not, i had actually solved up until the general implicit solution using the answer you wrote to some other example on the site before. The way i tried doing, with (y0,s) coordinate system causes some unresolvable equations, so i decided to jsut leave it. But the technique for figuring out the fucnction is also very nice , thank you!